# Driver binary downloader maven plugin - across multiple modules

Tags: java, maven, selenium

We've got a multi-module Selenium Maven project. Each module represents one application that is tested. We've also got a 'core' module which contains everything necessary for the whole setup (driver initialization, utils classes, etc.).

The problem is that we set the plugins and the repository map in every module's pom.xml - it's basically a copy-paste of the plugins and the repository map (this is it: [Lazery](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/08/12/introducing-the-driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin-for-selenium.html))

My question is: is it possible to set the plugins and the repository map in our core pom.xml so that it would be used by all the other modules that have a dependency on that core module? I'm not very well-versed in Maven, so so far I haven't been able to find a solution to this.

EDIT: I have managed to solve the plugin issue by using pluginManagement. However, the issue of the RepositoryMap.xml is still there. I need to have the map in every project's test resources in order for the driver-binary-downloader to start the driver.

Comment: Yes, you can put common plugins in root pom file and it will be available to all child module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the resources problem by placing the Repository Map into the core module and giving the plugin the path.

As mentioned in my edit in the question: the plugin issue was resolved with the pluginManagement